# Headless Browserify JavaScript Testing with Phantom.js

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, browserify, headless-browser

I'm trying to find a way to execute the following steps.

- Write Node.js code for the browser
- Compile the code with browserify
- Test the browser code in the terminal

I would love to get the `console.logs` that the browser receives, but within the terminal. This would not only save me time (from creating a HTML file, running a server, opening a browser), it would also allow for cool things like automatic testing before deployment.

I'm trying to make something called `headless-test.js` a `phantomjs` script that would get passed an argument using `system.args[1]` and `fs.read` can get the contents of any javascript you pass to it.

```
var content = fs.read(system.args[1])
page.content = '<html><body><script type="text/javascript">'+content+'</script></body></html>'
```

That would allow me to do something like this:

```
phantomjs ./headless-test.js ./bundle.js
```

I was getting this error `SyntaxError: Multiline comment was not closed properly` so make sure you uglify your `bundle.js`.

All of this would be amazing and work if I could get this demo below working. The minimal viable product:

```
var system = require("system")
var webPage = require('webpage')
var page = require('webpage').create()
page.content = '<html><body><script type="text/javascript">console.log("hello world")</script></body></html>';

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
  console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};

page.evaluate(function(){

})

phantom.exit();
```

The expected results here are:

```
$ phantomjs ./headless-test.js
hello world
```

However I'm getting no `stdout` from phantom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign something to `page.content` it is immediately evaluated, but you register to the `console.log()` from page context after that. You simply miss the `console.log()` from the script element in the page.

Move the `page.content` assignment after the `page.onConsoleMessage` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var system = require("system")
var webPage = require('webpage')
var page = require('webpage').create()

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
  console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
}

var fs = require("fs")
var content = fs.read(system.args[1])
page.content = '<html><body><script type="text/javascript">'+content+'</script></body></html>'

phantom.exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a node tool for this: https://github.com/mantoni/phantomic

If you should also want to use Mocha as a test framework, try Mochify (https://github.com/mantoni/mochify.js). It uses `phantomic` with `brout` to get the console output into the terminal properly.